# cart no, city and buttons are showing incorrect in Magento 2.2.7

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.2

Some how the city is not displaying during the cart summary. Also, another address is not clickable anymore, it is just an empty box.
I have checked with the repo, and it seems that all files are identical.

The city should display right next to the postal code.

Is there anybody out there to help me out?

Thank you very much!

[image: Picture of the issue]

Comment: This is happens becouse you done your custom changes in cart summary page,check your code or js.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No JS or major code has been changed in the cart summary page. I just checked for any differences within the original 2.2.7 repo and no differences were found. I believe it has something to do with the address-renderer. See this file for example:

https://hastebin.com/ufujoyowaq.xml

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155626)